# screen space in Android emulator in visual studio for mac is very small

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-mac

[image]
I have got the project up and running on android. But the problem with emulator is I cannot expand it to a bigger screen. Even if I expand the same amount of screen is visible.

The emulator I created is nexus 5 device running android 5.0.1 and uses a intel atom image x86

Comment: Please use the image button on the toolbar to upload images. It puts them in to Stack Overflow's area of imgur, which preserves them for long term availability in this question. It doesn't do any good to future readers when they look at the post and can no longer see the image.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite for the feedback. I have edited the question